# Page CSS "breaks" when I zoom with iphone

Tags: css

I spent all day forcing in a form on my blog pages, and after verifying it works with all browsers I go to my iphone..... and when I zoom with my iphone the form breaks and goes all over the page. This seems like something I can't let pass by because people need to zoom all the time with tiny iphones. [Please see](http://www.fishingreports.com/blog/thermocline), you can see the left-floated form.

If you try zooming with an internet browser it works fine. Iphone it doesn't work.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong/point me in the right direction?

Comment: There is difference between zooming browser and iPhone, (or phone). While in browser zoom you are scaling the content by %. Phone is a lot different because you are having different screen resolution. I recomend disablind zoom for phones `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />` if the site is responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you disable the fixed positioning on the iPhone, as it isn't doing you any favors (it's making the form unusable).

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 560px) {
    #signup {
        position: static;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ralph.

Unfortunately this method did not work. I'm not even seeing the position:static effect on my phone. Is there possibly a syntax error that I setup wrong?

Comment: You modified the code I gave above, adding `form` into the mix, but that's no use. It's not the form that has `position: fixed`, but the `#sighnup` div around it, so you need to target that. Try it with the code as I gave it: `#signup {`. Or did that not work?

Comment: #signup { didn't work, so I tried it with the form too. Either way, its acting like I'm not telling it to do anything.

I put it back to #signup { now...

Comment: Hm, it's odd that the media query doesn't work on the iPhone, as it's working on desktop. Just for fun, try adding this to the `<head>` of your document and see if it makes a difference: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`.

Comment: ....Yikes! When I added that tag to the <head> the PC version looked normal, but the page turned to gobbley-gook on the iphone.

Comment: OK, I thought it might. It's really for when you are doing a responsive site. Anyhow, it's odd that the desktop is getting that media rule but the iPhone isn't.

Comment: It's weird, but when checking your site on the iPhone with Firebug, it just doesn't see that @media rule. I wonder if it would help to add `!important`. `position: static !important;`

Comment: That didn't work either. Is there any chance theres some bootstrap stuff messing around with the settings?

Comment: Changed the min-width to 0px as I thought it might help. No luck either. Also succeeded to make h3 red in browser, but not phone.